# unable to convert string to json using JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript

json string:

```
str = "{'Link': 'https://careers.powergrid.in/CCBaclogVacancy2018/c/default.aspx',
'Title': 'Apply Online'},{'Link': 'https://careers.powergrid.in/CCBaclogVacancy2018/c/login.aspx',
'Title': 'Login'},{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/8588011698.pdf',
'Title': 'Notification '},{'Link': 'http://www.powergridindia.com/', 'Title': 'Official Website'}"
```

expecting:

```
json = {'Link': 'https://careers.powergrid.in/CCBaclogVacancy2018/c/default.aspx',
'Title': 'Apply Online'},{'Link': 'https://careers.powergrid.in/CCBaclogVacancy2018/c/login.aspx',
'Title': 'Login'},{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/8588011698.pdf',
'Title': 'Notification '},{'Link': 'http://www.powergridindia.com/', 'Title': 'Official Website'}
```

i am trying with JSON.parse(str);
it gives me error:

```
VM267:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at <anonymous>:1:6
```

How can i convert string to pure json.

please have a look into this.

Comment: Your Json is not correct.
your trying to convet some kind of Array of Jsons but your not putting it inside Array.

Comment: Property names and string values *must* be quoted with `"` characters in JSON.

Comment: is there any way to do this using regular expressions??

Comment: change all ' to " ?

Comment: no bro . it is coming from database

Comment: you'll need to format the string before parsing, but this DB is wrong, really wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.parse` expects a well formed string. JSON data is written as name/value pairs. A name/value pair consists of a field name (in double quotes), followed by a colon, followed by a value (in double quotes if its a string value).

In addition, it looks like you're attempting to describe a collection of objects, so you should wrap it all inside an array... (note i'm using a `` ES2015 string, that allows multiline strings)

```
const str = `[{
    "Link": "https://careers.powergrid.in/CCBaclogVacancy2018/c/default.aspx",
    "Title": "Apply Online"
},
{
    "Link": "https://careers.powergrid.in/CCBaclogVacancy2018/c/login.aspx",
    "Title": "Login"
},
{
    "Link": "media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/8588011698.pdf",
    "Title": "Notification "
},
{
    "Link": "http://www.powergridindia.com/",
    "Title": "Official Website"
}]`;
console.log(JSON.parse(str)[0].Title); // Apply Online
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "what 'ever'";
str = str.replace(/'/gi,'"')
```

this is the way to replace all with regexp and replace()

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: @KiranSyoutubechannel yes true my mistake. 
this is the right one.(editted)

Comment: it is changing ' to " but JSON.parse is showing error

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 1):

Your json is invalid.

- single quote should be double quote
- objects should be wrapped by `[]` which indicate array

so to make it valid json, wrap objects with brackets and replace all single quote, and then parse it.

```js
str = `[{'Link': 'https://careers.powergrid.in/CCBaclogVacancy2018/c/default.aspx',
'Title': 'Apply Online'},{'Link': 'https://careers.powergrid.in/CCBaclogVacancy2018/c/login.aspx',
'Title': 'Login'},{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/8588011698.pdf',
'Title': 'Notification '},{'Link': 'http://www.powergridindia.com/', 'Title': 'Official Website'}]`

json = JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g, '"'))
console.log(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the outermost wrapper for whatever array you have going on here. Also double quotes are the standard in json

Try wrapping your fields.

```
`{
   "items": [
      {
       "Link": "https://careers.powergrid.in/CCBaclogVacancy2018/c/default.aspx",
       "Title": "Apply Online"
      }, {
        "Link": "https://careers.powergrid.in/CCBaclogVacancy2018/c/login.aspx",
        "Title": "Login"
      }, {
        "Link": "media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/8588011698.pdf",
        "Title": "Notification"
      }, {
        "Link": "http://www.powergridindia.com",
        "Title": "Official Website"
      }
    ]
}`
```

Comment: Typo! You forgot opening the first object on the items array

Comment: Yeah. I'm doing this from a phone, so i have to submit to preview

Comment: Traditional strings doesn't support multiline, you should use `` or the old-nasty + after each line

Comment: @sminutoli yes that is true, I'm just trying to make the format more obvious. You'd have to remove the whitespace in actual use

Comment: @sminutoli Fixed